# getting ssh / repl for my existing scala project

Tags: scala, ssh, read-eval-print-loop

i was try to get an ssh working for my scala project. I tried searching online , but could not find any way i will be able integrate with the existing code . If someone has done this in scala , please let me know !!!

Comment: this question doesn't make sense.  please explain what you mean.

Comment: an ssh for your scala project? What the hell do you mean?

Comment: i have heard we can provide shell access to the existing code...Something like this project..https://github.com/sirthias/scala-ssh .. you can access the projects from command line..and i dont know how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have implemented the project. Its fairly simple . Just include the files and embed into the working Code. Should not take you more than five minutes. Let me know where you are having problem.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is pretty unclear, but *maybe* you mean that you want to be able to have the REPL be aware of your existing code?  This is a common problem because if you just run `scala` from the command line, you will start the REPL, but it won't be aware of your existing project's classes.

One common way to do this is to use [SBT](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki), which is a nice build manager that works with scala projects.  If you use SBT with your project, then you can run the command `sbt console` from the command line and it will start a REPL that is aware of your existing code.  Then you can just `import` classes the same way you would in normal code.

You can go to the [website](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki) to read about how to install SBT and how to set up SBT for your project.